# Replace first two string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
034521123455
034525245272
034223232322
034567754443
```

i want to replace "03" with "+92"

like this

```
+924521123455
+924525245272
+924223232322
+924567754443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concat+substring instead of the replace:

```
select concat('+92', SUBSTRING('034521123403',3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```
select CONCAT('+92', SUBSTRING('034521123455', 3));
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=443f6a6fc9c21b756715e7d71267224b)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` and `left()` function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5395e86e3a48a7836bc855dd7b5574e8)**

```
select replace('034521123455',left('034521123455',2),'+92')
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work. its show something like this 

+920+92496401
+92212131+921

but i only want to replace first two string not whole string..

Comment: @MuhammadSaad, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5395e86e3a48a7836bc855dd7b5574e8

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use [`insert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert):

```
select insert(col, 1, 2, '+92')
```

This function does specifically what you want.

If you need this done conditionally, then use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when col like '03%'
             then insert(col, 1, 2, '+92')
             else col
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code and its working fine

```
select replace(Col,'03','+92') from TableName
```